# Wordpress - WooCommerce - Hide orders with virtual products from My Orders Page and display them on their own page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We created an ecommerce website using WooCommerce for a nonprofit client that only sells physical products, e.g. books, cds and dvds. They've since asked us to integrate donations as well. I've set up a donation as a Virtual Product and gotten it working.

Currently, every order a customer makes, including ones with the donation product, is listed under the "Orders" tab under My Account. We need to separate out orders with the virtual donation product from regular physical product orders. I've yet to find a solution anywhere for this.

Ideally, if an order contains a virtual product, we want to hide it from the Orders Page, and instead create a tab called, "Donations" that shows ONLY orders with virtual products in a table. Is this even possible?

Comment: Is this even possible? certainly! The method that I would apply. 1) For new orders I would provide an field in the database, where when creating a order a true/false value is provided if the order contains virtual products. 2) Provide an new tab in my account 3) copy/paste the template file of the current order tab for the new tab. 4) modify the current template to load orders from the database where the value = false 5) apply the same for the new template file = true 6) execute a one-time SQL query that will update old orders with the new field (true/false) if they contain virtual products.

Comment: That sounds like it could work! I'm really new to this kind of stuff, though - how would I add the true/false value field to the database/order tabs? I can duplicate the current order tab easily enough.